# Почему кубик сдвигается вправо, хотя должен идти ровно по вертикали?

Tags: css

Вот код:

```css
.fa-chevron-double-down {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 34px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 14%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 animation: down 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes down {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(2rem);
 }
}
```

```html
<i class="fal fa-chevron-double-down"></i>
```

Comment: transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(2rem);

Comment: он сдвигается с -50% до 0%